# Getting text into variables not working from mediainfo

Tags: batch-file, mediainfo

I am building a simple script that I will be adding `ffmpeg` to after this part works.

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%B in (*.mp4,*.mkv) do (
    mediainfo.exe "--Inform=Video;%%Format%%" "%%B" > temp.txt
    for /f %%G in (temp.txt) do (set tester=%%G)
    echo test: %%G
    echo video: %tester%
)
pause
```

The `echo`'s have no data. The file `temp.txt` has the correct info. So the `mediainfo` command is working, but the `for /f` loop is not assigning the data to environment variable `tester`. I cannot use `EnableDelayedExpansion` because there could be exclamation marks in the file names. I also tried `set /p tester=<temp.txt` with the same results.

Here is the output in the command window:

```
test: %G
video:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what `%%Format%%` is supposed to be or do?

Comment: @Compo, %%Format%% is the option that picks the video format, ie AVC,HEVC, etc

Comment: Sorry, I was being deliberately cryptic, the main reason I asked was that as there are usually more than one `format` field names, I would have expected you to use `%%Format/String%%`, or `%%Format/String1%%`, instead. However, I was also aware that `%Format%` looked too much like a standard Windows variable, and didn't want others to complain that you were using a variable, you hadn't defined. _(Thanks at least for clarifying)_.

Comment: Because this is way too complicated, and it shouldn't be, I think a better approach is removing the exclamation mark from the filename before applying the EnableDelayedExpansion since that was the only reason I am not using EnableDelayedExpansion. Now I need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this was use a powershell script before the execution of the batch
here is the remove.ps1 file

`get-childitem -recurse -Include *.mp4 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("!", "") }`

here is what I added to the beginning of the bat file
Since I am only dealing with media files, I just wanted to remove the exclamation marks anyway. Or you can modify the PS script to substitute a different character.
Now the batch script can handle files that have exclamation marks.

`@echo off`
`pushd "G:\convert\files"`
`powershell -file G:\convert\remove.ps1`